# ShinyApps Error: Unhandled exception Child Task

Tags: r, git, shiny, shiny-server

Shinnyapps returns the error: **Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 524809012 error: Unhandled Exception: Timeout waiting for '_check_container_alive' after 0:00:30**

I have thoroughly searched for an answer. None are satisfactory. They range from *overloaded system, wrong R version, need Rcpp library*, *to the issue went away on its own.*

I am at standstill on (1) what is a child task and (2) how to debug it.

To fully understand shinyapps.io, I am using "simple website" code described in https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/rmarkdown_websites.html#html_generation. I cloned the code, https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown-website-examples/tree/master/common-elements, and ran it in Rstudio. **The code runs locally but fails to create an instance with shinyapps.io.**

Here is information that proves useful.

devtools::session_info() ─ Session info ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── setting value
version R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) os macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
system x86_64, darwin15.6.0
ui RStudio
language (EN)
collate en_US.UTF-8
tz America/New_York
date 2018-05-09
─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── package * version date source
ansistrings 1.0.0.9000 2018-04-12 Github (r-lib/ansistrings@4e4d309) assertthat 0.2.0 2017-04-11 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
backports 1.1.2 2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
bitops 1.0-6 2013-08-17 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
callr 2.0.3-9000 2018-04-29 Github (r-lib/callr@f3ee85a)
cli 1.0.0.9002 2018-04-12 Github (r-lib/cli@c408924)
clisymbols 1.2.0 2017-05-21 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
crayon 1.3.4 2018-04-12 Github (gaborcsardi/crayon@95b3eae) curl 3.2 2018-03-28 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
debugme 1.1.0 2017-10-22 CRAN (R 3.4.2)
desc 1.2.0 2018-05-01 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
devtools 1.13.5.9000 2018-04-12 Github (hadley/devtools@13ee56b)
digest 0.6.15 2018-01-28 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
evaluate 0.10.1 2017-06-24 CRAN (R 3.4.1)
git2r 0.21.0.9002 2018-04-12 Github (ropensci/git2r@198b4d6)
glue 1.2.0 2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.4.2)
hms 0.4.2 2018-03-10 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
htmltools 0.3.6 2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
httpuv 1.4.2 2018-05-03 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
httr 1.3.1 2017-08-20 CRAN (R 3.4.1)
knitr 1.20 2018-02-20 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
later 0.7.2 2018-05-01 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
magrittr 1.5 2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
memoise 1.1.0 2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
mime 0.5 2016-07-07 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
packrat 0.4.9-2 2018-04-20 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
pkgbuild 1.0.0 2018-04-12 Github (r-lib/pkgbuild@4ee12af)
pkgconfig 2.0.1 2017-03-21 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
pkgload 1.0.0 2018-04-12 Github (r-lib/pkgload@a9184a0)
prettyunits 1.0.2 2015-07-13 CRAN (R 3.4.2)
progress 1.1.2.9003 2018-04-12 Github (r-lib/progress@e525de4)
promises 1.0.1 2018-04-13 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
R6 2.2.2 2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
Rcpp 0.12.16 2018-03-13 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
RCurl 1.95-4.10 2018-01-04 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
RJSONIO * 1.3-0 2014-07-28 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
rlang 0.2.0 2018-02-20 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
rmarkdown 1.9.9 2018-04-29 Github (rstudio/rmarkdown@91d071f) rprojroot 1.3-2 2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
rsconnect * 0.8.8 2018-03-09 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
selectr 0.4-1 2018-04-06 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
sessioninfo 1.0.1.9000 2018-04-12 Github (r-lib/sessioninfo@c871d01) shiny * 1.0.5 2017-08-23 CRAN (R 3.4.1)
stringi 1.2.2 2018-05-02 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
stringr 1.3.0 2018-02-19 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
testthat 2.0.0 2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
usethis 1.3.0.9000 2018-04-12 Github (r-lib/usethis@acd9e70)
withr 2.1.2 2018-03-15 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
xml2 1.2.0 2018-01-24 CRAN (R 3.4.2)
xtable 1.8-2 2016-02-05 CRAN (R 3.4.0)
yaml 2.1.19 2018-05-01 CRAN (R 3.4.4)

deployApp(appName= "rmarkdown-website-examples-master", account = "pjossenbruggen")
GET /v1/applications/339665 202ms Update application currently deployed at https://pjossenbruggen.shinyapps.io/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/? [Y/n] y POST /v1/bundles 155ms PUT /bundles/application-339665/d8293c7d29e3424d844a5d6d4121a6a4.tar.gz?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAJRPFLVMEXVLP2ZOQ&x-amz-acl=bucket-owner-full-control&Expires=1525875859&content-md5=XUtAQkqB3OIQnqTpY2LQ7Q%3D%3D&x-amz-security-token=FQoDYXdzENP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaDCJdLNaFL%2F4IQRAzSyK3A4XeLhnHekKjy91V84ceofjnNI6fqmfymrIxNDk%2FICwNZFeOlsZeSO8oGPjtgTn%2B4IT6isGhNnoxKhFevbtcoXsmMVSTCXSZOnCIHZkOA5D8wkZpmbijHvHTgyEQHPvqYI7vMnlCDawzDASDxuKDE5WZ43IH%2FkJ8t8QzQcBRr0xZ7nMAcX6ECL9OnRcbo3MZQnTi49r55B3GxZqlj3PKQ6L1IvFUPD51qtuCC%2FmNSM5zvThEoi%2FvXjwLtIIOvxe9%2Bsn4DXQfN1rL3g79CxnQ24GDmjb8MFKHqW1FGydkWbzGOiBdnw3N6kCUfheV%2BUkPImbYwL9EQnNhVNWJ7hVrpqvvDOQa0cUjk8GypPdiYbIV7C4TsKLz9s9kh7bn8rjeM3dMrtUymssuLCmfMuPZXw5x4ph1fN5eVxaWFoagw%2F9ZDGApjprnd4Gdn7lzsmaw3Ty39mLIBnTwqjHBxaFrg5jNJHAz8gBsyuHFgyIup24JABYwq1VEGN5vN8HR5t2oM6idgrh8FoqXmCDJLWhfOgSkwkEJcGrhflbFcLDdhvsh215IMytO0kDIbI0vsWX5fAy8ecrScTwosozL1wU%3D&Signature=FjyDzFDSRG6CqnuCRvolDWcFrFQ%3D&content-type=application%2Fx-tar 1133ms POST /v1/bundles/1364681/status 171ms GET /v1/bundles/1364681 147ms POST /v1/applications/339665/deploy 266ms Waiting for task: 524808975 GET /v1/tasks/524808975 150ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 129ms building: Parsing manifest GET /v1/tasks/524808975 168ms building: Installing files GET /v1/tasks/524808975 148ms building: Pushing image: 1377617 GET /v1/tasks/524808975 135ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 116ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 156ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 127ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 124ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 348ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 228ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 137ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 137ms deploying: Starting instances GET /v1/tasks/524808975 133ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 120ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 120ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 132ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 134ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 147ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 220ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 129ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 127ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 131ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 172ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 232ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 158ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 140ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 131ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 133ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 334ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 133ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 206ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 136ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 125ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 141ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 144ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 133ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 148ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 144ms GET /v1/tasks/524808975 130ms

#################### Begin Task Log

GET /v1/tasks/524808975/logs/ 122ms GET /v1/tasks/?filter=account_id:117689&filter=parent_id:524808975&count=100&offset=0 140ms GET /v1/tasks/524809012/logs/ 169ms GET /v1/tasks/?filter=account_id:117689&filter=parent_id:524809012&count=100&offset=0 115ms GET /v1/tasks/524809002/logs/ 170ms GET /v1/tasks/?filter=account_id:117689&filter=parent_id:524809002&count=100&offset=0 134ms GET /v1/tasks/524809000/logs/ 150ms GET /v1/tasks/?filter=account_id:117689&filter=parent_id:524809000&count=100&offset=0 131ms GET /v1/tasks/524808998/logs/ 116ms GET /v1/tasks/?filter=account_id:117689&filter=parent_id:524808998&count=100&offset=0 127ms GET /v1/tasks/524808978/logs/ 158ms Generating locales... en_US.UTF-8... done Generation complete. [2018-05-09T13:24:24.626823401+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master [2018-05-09T13:24:24.629896809+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/common-elements [2018-05-09T13:24:24.632622700+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/common-elements/_site [2018-05-09T13:24:24.635294559+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/common-elements/_site/site_libs [2018-05-09T13:24:24.637964956+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5 [2018-05-09T13:24:24.640641584+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css [2018-05-09T13:24:24.643307787+0000] Copying file common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/simplex.min.css [2018-05-09T13:24:24.646379218+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/hello-website [2018-05-09T13:24:24.649078247+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/hello-website/_site [2018-05-09T13:24:24.651768815+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/hello-website/_site/site_libs [2018-05-09T13:24:24.654403517+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5 [2018-05-09T13:24:24.657032623+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css [2018-05-09T13:24:24.659720196+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/paper.min.css [2018-05-09T13:24:24.662641717+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/fonts [2018-05-09T13:24:24.665282947+0000] Copying file common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot [2018-05-09T13:24:24.668108803+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/fonts [2018-05-09T13:24:24.670897730+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/fonts/OpenSansLight.ttf [2018-05-09T13:24:24.673728920+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/fonts/RobotoBold.ttf [2018-05-09T13:24:24.676673513+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/js [2018-05-09T13:24:24.679442525+0000] Copying file common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js [2018-05-09T13:24:24.682299964+0000] Copying file common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/cosmo.min.css [2018-05-09T13:24:24.685146233+0000] Copying file common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css [2018-05-09T13:24:24.687951773+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/index.html [2018-05-09T13:24:24.690822207+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/fonts [2018-05-09T13:24:24.693522141+0000] Copying file common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/fonts/Lato.ttf [2018-05-09T13:24:24.696405593+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/fonts/RalewayBold.ttf [2018-05-09T13:24:24.699235048+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/fonts/OpenSans.ttf [2018-05-09T13:24:24.702014942+0000] Copying file common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css.map [2018-05-09T13:24:24.705099894+0000] Copying file common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/flatly.min.css [2018-05-09T13:24:24.708032601+0000] Copying file common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js [2018-05-09T13:24:24.710913954+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/journal.min.css [2018-05-09T13:24:24.713732128+0000] Copying file common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/fonts/RobotoBold.ttf [2018-05-09T13:24:24.716621418+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/fonts/RobotoMedium.ttf [2018-05-09T13:24:24.719463294+0000] Copying file common-elements/_site/footer.html [2018-05-09T13:24:24.722204911+0000] Copying file common-elements/footer.html [2018-05-09T13:24:24.724963097+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/common-elements/_site/site_libs/navigation-1.1 [2018-05-09T13:24:24.727656047+0000] Copying file common-elements/_site/site_libs/navigation-1.1/tabsets.js [2018-05-09T13:24:24.730402914+0000] Copying file common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/fonts/OpenSansLightItalic.ttf [2018-05-09T13:24:24.733179684+0000] Copying file common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg [2018-05-09T13:24:24.736026953+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/shim [2018-05-09T13:24:24.738724717+0000] Copying file common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/shim/html5shiv.min.js [2018-05-09T13:24:24.741509906+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/hello-website/_site/site_libs/navigation-1.1 [2018-05-09T13:24:24.744195343+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/site_libs/navigation-1.1/tabsets.js [2018-05-09T13:24:24.746973657+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/fonts/NewsCycle.ttf [2018-05-09T13:24:24.749773161+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/united.min.css [2018-05-09T13:24:24.752566595+0000] Copying file README.html [2018-05-09T13:24:24.755786863+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/fonts/Ubuntu.ttf [2018-05-09T13:24:24.758610099+0000] Copying file common-elements/about.Rmd [2018-05-09T13:24:24.761375689+0000] Copying file hello-website/.DS_Store [2018-05-09T13:24:24.764215819+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/spacelab.min.css [2018-05-09T13:24:24.767117380+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/fonts [2018-05-09T13:24:24.769741528+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff [2018-05-09T13:24:24.772575385+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/gh-pages [2018-05-09T13:24:24.775212216+0000] Copying file gh-pages/.DS_Store [2018-05-09T13:24:24.777943340+0000] Copying file common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/fonts/OpenSansBold.ttf [2018-05-09T13:24:24.780848349+0000] Creating dir /srv/connect/apps/rmarkdown-website-examples-master/hello-website/_site/site_libs/highlightjs-9.12.0 [2018-05-09T13:24:24.783535677+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/site_libs/highlightjs-9.12.0/highlight.js [2018-05-09T13:24:24.786331931+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/sandstone.min.css [2018-05-09T13:24:24.789171176+0000] Copying file common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf [2018-05-09T13:24:24.792064024+0000] Copying file gh-pages/_site.yml [2018-05-09T13:24:24.794833101+0000] Copying file gh-pages/about.Rmd [2018-05-09T13:24:24.797527371+0000] Copying file common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/fonts/OpenSansBoldItalic.ttf [2018-05-09T13:24:24.800346116+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/lumen.min.css [2018-05-09T13:24:24.803254431+0000] Copying file common-elements/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/sandstone.min.css [2018-05-09T13:24:24.806070231+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/cosmo.min.css [2018-05-09T13:24:24.808969742+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.css.map [2018-05-09T13:24:24.811820328+0000] Copying file hello-website/_site/site_libs/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css.map [2018-05-09T13:24:24.814815448+0000] Copying file coGET /v1/tasks/?filter=account_id:117689&filter=parent_id:524808978&count=100&offset=0 125ms

##################### End Task Log

Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 524809012 error: Unhandled Exception: Timeout waiting for '_check_container_alive' after 0:00:30